# how to force subclasses/ protocols in generics

Tags: generics, swift

I have a protocol:

```
protocol CXSummarizable:Hashable,Equatable{
    func summary() -> (title:String,subTitle:String,icon:CXImage,identifier:CXIdentifier);
}
```

I'd like to make a dictionary of arrays that all follow this protocol.

`Dictionary<CXSummarizeable,Array<CXSummarizeable>>`

Is there some special syntax to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to make a dictionary of arrays that all follow this protocol.

You can do that like this.

```
var result: [CXSummarizeable:[CXSummarizeable]] = [:];
//           ^ key type      ^ value type         ^ empty dictionary
```

You define the type of the dictionary as a dictionary that has keys of type `CXSummarizeable` and values of type `[CXSummarizeable]`. Then assign an empty dictionary literal `[:]` to that variable.

You can then start inserting data.